# New Idea for accessing memory across an inter-network connected system

Tags: operating-systems, distributed-systems, computer-networks, memory-management, memory-access

I have the following idea for a network-based operating system.

Suppose we have two computers *A* and *B* in a network. If computer *B* wants to access the memory of computer *A*, it can access by using the following addressing method which uses Media Access Control (*MAC*) address of the machines,

```
(MAC Address of target machine).(memory address on target machine)
```

This should work both ways as well as all the computers connected in a network. This will also remove the constraint of passing reference of variables in Remote Procedure Call (*RPC*).

Is the above method feasible ? What sort of modifications are required to make this possible, if feasible ?

NOTE:-I am also assuming that there is no MAC spoofing.

Comment: What do you mean by "is it feasible"?  Why *wouldn't* it be feasible?  Have you done any research, e.g., looking at the research literature on Google Scholar?

Comment: That's not an addressing method, it's just two things written down next to each other. And assuming that there are no security problems is a great way to build an insecure system.

Answer (score 1):

This would be an instance of a [distributed shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_shared_memory) architecture.  There's been *lots* of research on such systems.  I would recommend spending some quality time on Google Scholar to read relevant research papers on those kinds of systems, to learn about what's been tried so far.

You might also be interested in the literature on distributed in-memory databases, caches, and data stores.